# How to Change the message position in magento?

Tags: magento

I need change the message(error/success) position in magento. By default magento message(error/success) show inside the wrapper or content. But I need to show the message in the top of the page. Can any one help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: I like that idea.  Maybe send a screenshot of what it looks like!  Sounds nice.

Comment: You are creating your own template. What about the previous messages which are displaying? Like cart messages and newsletter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Here is one which requires a little layout xml and a new template at a minimum…

Layout:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.messages" template="core/messages/top.phtml" before="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Template:  ( app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/core/messages/top.phtml )

```
<?php $_messageCollection = $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessageCollection() ?>

<?php if ($_messageCollection->count()): ?>
<div>
<?php
    echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
    $_messageCollection->clear();
?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move the block in your layout xml files. Unfortunately, I don't have Magento at hand to tell you what's the block name, and where it's defined.